# Compare two lists, for every match return value from adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[List A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hvt1.png) contains magic items and some of their properties in a table. [List B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJqVb.png) contains the character's inventory in a single cell. I am trying to create a formula that returns the values from column D from List A for every item that exists in List B, in a single output. In this specific case, the desired output would be "Force damage, Acid damage" or similar.

In an attempt to do so I've turned List B into a column with separate values in every row, rather than one cell, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7qLH.png). This allows me to VLOOKUP the information I need. This is, however, a very messy approach as I have to manually determine the maximum number of items to check, and due to the Value Not Available and 0 values I can't compile this information in clean way.

The only similar issue I was able to find is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1542625/compare-two-columns-in-a-table-and-if-it-matches-return-a-value-in-another-colum), however it has not been answered yet due to a lack of example data.

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking to achieve. What is your desired end state?

Comment: Also, TIL "brooch" and "broach" are two different words

Comment: Apologies for not explaining well enough. I'll edit the question for clarity as well, what I am trying to achieve: For all items on List A (magic items) that are present in List B (inventory), return the values from a specific column in List A (column D in the example) in a single output. With the example data, the desired end state would be a formula that outputs "Acid damage, Force damage" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a UDF like this one:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function Magistry(Itemlist As Range, Inventory As Range, Attributes As Range)

On Error GoTo Catcher
Dim MyList As Variant, Powers As String, c As Variant, i As Long, n As Long

MyList = Split(Inventory, Chr(10))
n = 1
For Each c In Itemlist
    For i = LBound(MyList) To UBound(MyList)
        If MyList(i) = c And Attributes(c.Row, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            If n = 1 Then
                Powers = Attributes(c.Row, 1)
                n = 0
                Else
                Powers = Powers + ", " & Attributes(c.Row, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next c

Magistry = Powers
Exit Function
Catcher:
Magistry = "You Lose"
End Function
```

Use ALTF11 to enter the developer window, insert a module then copy and paste this function. return to excel and use as a formula:

```
=magistry(ItemList, Inventory, Attributes)
```

[image: Magistry Example]

Comment: Thank you for this example! Although my Excel seems to struggle a little to execute the code, it does indeed do what I need it to - almost. It now also includes empty fields if items exist that have no attribute of the type that is being compiled. The output I get with my current information becomes "Force damage, , Acid damage, " now.

Comment: I have edited the example to allow for the null strings, what do you mean excel struggles a little? I don't think it should have a problem. How many lines/rows are you working with?

Comment: i just added the "Option Compare Text" line which prevents issues if you forget to capitalise things, if this is not an issue you can leave it out.